# CRC Bluetooth Low Energy 4.2

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, checksum, crc

In the core bluetooth 4.2 documentation [here](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=286439&_ga=2.156786354.849882776.1501666472-1386832473.1501666472) it talks about a CRC check for data integrity (P2456). This details the below:

[image]

With an example below:

4e 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09

Producing CRC: 6d d2

I have tried a number of different methods but can't seem to reproduce the example. Can anyone provide some sample code to produce the CRC above.

Answer (score 3):

You left out a key part of the example in the document, which is that the UAP used in the example is `0x47`. The CRC needs to be initialized with the UAP. (Oddly, with the bits reversed and in the high byte, relative to the data bits coming in.)

The code below computes the example. The result is `d26d`. The CRC is transmitted least significant bit first, so it is sent `6d d2`. On the receive side the same CRC is computed on the whole thing with the CRC, and the result is zero, which is how the receive side is supposed to check what was sent.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned crc_blue(unsigned char *payload, size_t len) {
    unsigned crc = 0xe200;      // UAP == 0x47
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= *payload++;
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0x8408 : crc >> 1;
    }
    return crc;
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned char payload[] = {
        0x4e, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09};
    printf("%04x\n", crc_blue(payload, sizeof(payload)));
    unsigned char recvd[] = {
        0x4e, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x6d, 0xd2};
    printf("%04x\n", crc_blue(recvd, sizeof(recvd)));
    return 0;
}
```

Your code would need to initialize the UAP appropriately for that device.